# SQLite trace for logging

Tags: swift, sqlite

I'm trying to debug some SQLite queries in my code using [tracing](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/trace_v2.html) to just log to the console everything that happens, but there seems to be almost no information on it - a Google search for "sqlite3_trace_v2 swift" only returns two pages of results, none of which were helpful except the above link.  Using the following code, I was able to get it to the point where it at least runs the trace callback:

```
func traceSQL (database: OpaquePointer?) {
    var pointer: OpaquePointer?
    func traceCallback (mask: UInt32, pointer: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?, query: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?, result: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) -> Int32 {
        print("SQLite Trace:")

        if let query = query?.load(as: UnsafePointer<Int8>.self) {
            print(String(cString: query))
        } else {
            print("Could not load query.")
        }

        if let result = result?.load(as: UnsafePointer<Int8>.self) {
            print(String(cString: result))
        } else {
            print("Could not load result.")
        }

        return 0
    }
    sqlite3_trace_v2(database, 15, traceCallback as @convention(c) (UInt32, UnsafeMutableRawPointer?, UnsafeMutableRawPointer?, UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) -> Int32, &pointer)
}
```

but I can't figure out what to do with the output of the function - currently, it just prints out a string of unreadable characters, and my previous attempts didn't even manage that.  I suspect at least part of the problem is that I don't really know how to work with `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` in Swift (something else that seems to be lacking in available information).

tl;dr: How do I log tracing results from SQLite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main error in your code is that you *derefence* the raw pointers
passed to the callback instead of *reinterpreting* (casting) them.
Also the meaning of those pointers is different for the different
events.

Here is an example how to trace the various events and how to convert
the raw pointers to the "correct" types, using a literal closure
as callback. The comments explaining the meaning of the `p` and `x`
argument are taken from [SQL Trace Event Codes](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/c_trace.html).

```swift
let traceMask = SQLITE_TRACE_STMT|SQLITE_TRACE_PROFILE|SQLITE_TRACE_ROW|SQLITE_TRACE_CLOSE

sqlite3_trace_v2(database, UInt32(traceMask), { (reason, context, p, x) -> Int32 in
    switch Int32(reason) {
    case SQLITE_TRACE_STMT:
        // The P argument is a pointer to the prepared statement.
        // The X argument is a pointer to a string which is the unexpanded SQL text 
        guard
            let pStmt = OpaquePointer(p),
            let cSql = x?.assumingMemoryBound(to: CChar.self)
        else {
            return 0
        }

        let sql = String(cString: cSql) // The unexpanded SQL text
        let expandedSql = String(cString: sqlite3_expanded_sql(pStmt)) // The expanded SQL text
        print("SQLITE_TRACE_STMT:", expandedSql)

    case SQLITE_TRACE_PROFILE:
        // The P argument is a pointer to the prepared statement and the X argument points
        // to a 64-bit integer which is the estimated of the number of nanosecond that the
        // prepared statement took to run.
        guard
            let pStmt = OpaquePointer(p),
            let duration = x?.load(as: UInt64.self)
        else {
            return 0
        }

        let milliSeconds = Double(duration)/Double(NSEC_PER_MSEC)
        let sql = String(cString: sqlite3_sql(pStmt)) // The unexpanded SQL text
        print("SQLITE_TRACE_PROFILE:", milliSeconds, "ms for statement:", sql)

    case SQLITE_TRACE_ROW:
        // The P argument is a pointer to the prepared statement and the X argument is unused.
        guard
            let pStmt = OpaquePointer(p)
        else {
            return 0
        }

        print("SQLITE_TRACE_ROW")

    case SQLITE_TRACE_CLOSE:
        // The P argument is a pointer to the database connection object and the X argument is unused.
        guard
            let database = OpaquePointer(p)
        else {
            return 0
        }

        print("SQLITE_TRACE_CLOSE")

    default:
        break
    }
    return 0
}, nil)
```

Of course you can restrict the trace mode to the events that you
are interesting in, e.g.

```swift
let traceMask = SQLITE_TRACE_STMT
```

to trace only prepared statements.